# Can't Build Project by Gradle Operation Timeout Issue

Tags: macos, android-gradle-plugin

I have trying to configue the setup and rebuild the project again but there has alwasy Operation Timeout. WOuld you please tell me how to setup gradles in local ? Even I have changed the link as :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5.1-all.zip
```

Still not working.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-
```

all.zip

The below is my gradle 3.3 file. It always shows  incomplete download.

[image: I have tried]

Part of Log File  :

```
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2017-07-06 10:46:56,427 [ 603845]   WARN - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - NDK support for project 'NovaX' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations. 
2017-07-06 10:46:56,579 [ 603997]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-07-06 10:46:56,579 [ 603997]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-07-06 10:46:56,581 [ 603999]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-07-06 10:46:56,582 [ 604000]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-07-06 10:47:50,698 [ 658116]   INFO - ntellij.util.proxy.CommonProxy - <html>You have JVM property "https.proxyHost" set to "proxy.cei-hk.com".<br>This may lead to incorrect behaviour. Proxy should be set in Settings | HTTP Proxy<br>This JVM property is old and its usage is not recommended by Oracle.<br>(Note: It could have been assigned by some code dynamically.) 
2017-07-06 10:48:11,639 [ 679057]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:145)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
```

Comment: Pay attention to the warning _You have JVM property "https.proxyHost" set_. Have you tried building this from the command line to figure out whether this is an issue with your IntelliJ only?

Comment: How to check this out ?

Comment: Check what out?

Comment: I am currently using android studio 2.3.3 and cannot find any issues caused even setting the proxy , distribution link and working gradles offline. I don't know how to check if IntelliJ works well or not. I am only using mac bundle.

Comment: Do you mean by running the command like  :  ./gradlew tasks --offline ?

Comment: Seems org.gradle.jvmargs has got some issues .